# Is the limit of a discrete stochastic process, which is adapted to a reverse filtration, measurable w.r.t. the limit sigma-algebra?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, and for every $n \in \{1,2,\dots\}$ let $\mathcal{F}_n$ be a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{F}$. Suppose that for every $n \in \{1,2,\dots\}$ $\mathcal{F}_{n+1}\subseteq\mathcal{F}_n$ (in other words, $(\mathcal{F}_1,\mathcal{F}_2,\dots)$ is a reverse filtration).

For every $n \in \{1,2,\dots\}$ let $X_n : (\Omega,\mathcal{F}_n)\rightarrow(\overline{\mathbb{R}},\mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}}))$ be an extended random variable, and let $X_{\infty} : (\Omega,\mathcal{F})\rightarrow(\overline{\mathbb{R}},\mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}}))$ be an extended random variable such that $X_{\infty} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_n$.

Define $\mathcal{F}_{\infty} = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{F}_n$. Is it true that $X_{\infty} : (\Omega,\mathcal{F}_{\infty})\rightarrow(\overline{\mathbb{R}},\mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}}))$?

---

**Remark**

If the sequence $(\mathcal{F}_1,\mathcal{F}_2,\dots)$ were increasing rather than decresing (in other words, if it were a filtration rather than a reverse filtration), and if $\mathcal{F}_{\infty}$ were defined as $\sigma(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{F}_n)$, then we would indeed have $X_{\infty}: (\Omega,\mathcal{F}_{\infty})\rightarrow(\overline{\mathbb{R}},\mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}}))$, since then we would have $X_n: (\Omega,\mathcal{F}_{\infty})\rightarrow(\overline{\mathbb{R}},\mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}}))$ for every $n \in \{1,2,\dots\}$. However, under the given assumptions it can't be assumed that $X_n: (\Omega,\mathcal{F}_{\infty})\rightarrow(\overline{\mathbb{R}},\mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}}))$ for every $n \in \{1,2,\dots\}$.

Comment: If it would be true, then $\mathbb P\{X_\infty\leq x \}\in \{0,1\}$ for all $x$ what is unlikely true...

Comment: @Surb: So [this](https://imgur.com/a/cECOEcR) theorem is not true?

Comment: There are of course some situation where it can be true... but it's not true in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have $X_{\infty} (\omega)=\lim X_n(\omega)$ for each $\omega$.

Fix $k$. Then $X_n : (\Omega, \mathcal F_k) \to (\overline{\mathbb{R}},\mathcal{B})$ is measurable for each $n \geq k$. This implies that $X_{\infty} :(\Omega, \mathcal F_k) \to (\overline{\mathbb{R}},\mathcal{B})$ is measurable. The inverse image of any set $E$ in $\mathcal{B}$ under $X_{\infty}$ belongs to  $\mathcal F_k$ for each $k$ and hence to $\mathcal F_{\infty}$. QED